# Ubuntu Server PHP5 throws 500 internal server error while there are errors in the PHP file

Tags: linux, php, 500

I am trying to fix this problem for 4 days now. If there is a error in my php file it's throwing a 500 internal server error.

php.ini:

```
 display_errors = On
   Default Value: On
   Development Value: On
   Production Value: Off
```

I want it so it shows the errors on the page and not in the log file. In the log file I see there is missing a ; but I want that to show on the page.

Answer (score 1):

You also need `error_reporting = 2147483647` in your php.ini file. This will force a display of all errors.